# How to set the filename encoding globally for a python interpreter?

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, filenames

In a project, we need to open many files all over the place in the source code. We know that all filenames on disk are encoded in utf-8 and all filenames are proceed as Unicode internally.

Is there a way to set the filename encoding globally for the running interpreter, so that we change the following command:

```
open(filename.encode('utf-8'))
```

to this simpler version:

```
open(filename)
```

This would reduces errors and confusion among the developers. We use python 2.7.

Comment: What is `filename`?  How is its value set?

Comment: Is something like `def utf_open(filename): return open(filename.encode('utf-8'))` possible?

Comment: filename is a Unicode string. Its value come from various sources like database, the file system etc.

Comment: @IanAuld This might be the best approach in order to avoid clashes with system functionality. However, people need to know this function exists.

Comment: Your developers should know what methods/functions are available to them from any external/in house libraries. Do you have a `utils` modules or something like that you could stick it in?

Comment: @IanAuld Sure. Guess why we don't find it anymore? ;) It is just too big. So, this is why sometimes we agree on common behavior in order to simplify things.

Comment: If your devs won't see/ignore an email/commit message/etc. about there being a new tool for them to use they certainly won't be aware that `open` may or may not work differently depending on what file they are working in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is really what you meant (and not the encoding of the file's *contents*), this would do it:

```
open = lambda fname, *a, **kw: __builtins__.open(fname.encode('utf-8'), *a, **kw)
```

This will only affect modules that include (or import) the redefinition, so it's  reasonably safe.  But it might be less confusing, and certainly less trouble-prone over the long run, to provide a different command for opening files in your environment for which this applies:

```
def fsopen(fname, *args, **kwargs):
    """(explain when and why you want this)"""
    return open(fname.encode('utf-8'), *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer as well. Not sure how I can reward you as well. :/

Comment: Well, you can upvote all answers that you find helpful (click on the up arrow). And accept the answer that solved your problem. When there are multiple equivalent answers, choose the clearest/most complete one. Other things being equal, people usually choose the first correct answer.

Comment: Thanks again. Unfortunately, I need more reputation points to upvote this anwer. Stay tuned. ;)

Comment: PS. You'll find that if you implement the accepted answer, you won't be able to open files for writing. :-)

Comment: You are right. If you would include a warning like he did, I might be inclined to accept your answer as "the more" correct version. ;)

Comment: A warning about what?

Comment: Ah, okay. Nevermind. Looks good anyway. Was thinking about overriding the global \_\_builtin\_\_.open.

Comment: You're right: Assigning to `__builtin__.open` is a very different matter. This redefinition will only affect calls to `open` from modules that include it. Calls in other modules remain unaffected, even if they are called from a module that includes the redefinition. I commented on that above. _My_ concern is that changing the behavior of built-ins is confusing to future **readers**.

Comment: Exactly. So, this would be less an issue if python itself would provide such a function. Again, thanks for your effort. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such option, because the `open` function has documented behaviour *not* to UTF-8 encode the strings.

There's a simple reason for this: `open` is more or less just a delegate of the underlying OS function, and must work on any string that the OS function would work with. Hence, it expects raw Python strings and not unicode.

If you need this, implement a wrapper function to do this.
In Python, you can just override the local name -- or the global one, for that matter:

```
__uni_open = lambda string: __builtins__.open(string.encode("utf-8"))
open = __uni_open
```

in whatever module all your applications work with.

I don't recommend doing this -- it might break stuff beyond your project's control.

Comment: Concern noted and might be a valid reason not to do it.